# Defining a relation on a set with conditions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Define a relation R on R (All Real Numbers) as follows: For all real numbers x and y mTn if and only if 3 | (m - n).

I'm not sure what the vertical bar here means. Normally it means "such as" but that doesn't make sense in this context so what does it mean? Thank you!

EDIT: So would the answer to this question be R = { (x,y) | 3 | (x - y) }?

Comment: Perhaps you mean for all integers $m, n$ you have the relation $mTn$ if and only if $3|(m-n)$?  I don't see what the $x,y$ have to do with anything, and the "divides" condition is kind of silly if you're dealing with reals.

Comment: It seems to be the definition of congruence moduulo $3$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: So the vertical  bar doesn't mean divide? Oh, and is my solution correct?

Comment: The vertical bar does mean divides... it is the same as saying $m\equiv n \mod 3$ (that is what @Bernard is pointing out).

Comment: @TravisJ Ok. Did I solve the problem correctly though?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is... there is no question here other than what does the vertical bar mean.

Comment: @TravisJ The very first sentence/paragraph is the problem and my solution is listed right next to the edit.

Comment: @TravisJ Is the relation above either reflexive, symmetric, or transitive?

Comment: Yes on all three accounts.  I'll show the easy ones here: if $3|(m-n)$ does $3|(n-m)$?  Note that $(m-n)=-(n-m)$.  This is for symmetry.  Reflexive is easy, doe $3|(m-m)$, i.e. does $3|0$?

Comment: @TravisJ Thank you Travis!

Comment: I guess | means "divides" and, for instance, m = 3 + x and n = 15 + x for any real x then mTn. It is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no question there, and nothing that demands a solution. The text

> Define a relation $R$ on $\mathbb R$ as follows: For all real numbers $x$ and $y$, $mRn$ if and only if $3 \mid (m - n)$.

is not an exercise, and it doesn't ask you to **do** anything. On the contrary, the quoted text **is** a definition of $R$.

(Here I'm ignoring that it seems to confuse $x$ and $y$ for $m$ and $n$; I suspect you have copy-pasted a bit too eagerly from your earlier question).

If the text appears on a homework sheet, it is *not* because you're expected to give a definition of $R$ in your answer (because the text on the sheet *is* the definition) -- it is just there to tell *you* what $R$ means in the text *below* what you quote is speaking about. (Presumably there will be some kind of question about the $R$ that was just defined).

---

As others have noted in comments, $3\mid (m-n)$ means the $m-n$ is an (integer) multiple of $3$.

Comment: Ah, I see... I feel stupid for missing that haha.... The question asks whether the relation that you have quoted is a either reflexive, symmetric, or transitive @Henning Makholm.